# Out of Memory is generated using Camel JDBC component

Tags: postgresql, apache-camel, jdbctemplate

I have huge records (about 4500k) in database on postgres.
I want to extract the records and generate the huge file.

I have made below route.

**Route**

```
    <route id="fileRoute">
        <from uri="timer://timer1?period=2s&amp;repeatCount=1"/>
        <setBody>
            <constant>
                SELECT * FROM TRANS_ONLINE_TRM_HST
            </constant>
        </setBody>
        <to uri="jdbc:dataSource?outputType=StreamList&amp;resetAutoCommit=false" />
        <split streaming="true" parallelProcessing="true">
            <simple>${body}</simple>
            <convertBodyTo id="_convertBodyTo3" type="java.lang.String"/>
            <toD id="_toD1" uri="file:/test/outBox/lotte?fileName=AAAA.DAT&amp;fileExist=Append"/>
        </split>
    </route>
</routes>
```

After route start, I recieved out of memory exception.

```
ID-DESKTOP-0AE8A58-1577885403576-0-1 >>> (fileRoute) setBody[SELECT * FROM TRANS_ONLINE_TRM_HST] --> jdbc://dataSource?outputType=StreamList&resetAutoCommit=false <<<
, Pattern:InOnly
, Headers:{breadcrumbId=ID-DESKTOP-0AE8A58-1577885403576-0-1, firedTime=Wed Jan 01 22:30:08 KST 2020}
, BodyType:String
, Body:SELECT * FROM TRANS_ONLINE_TRM_HST


Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "http-nio-8912-ClientPoller"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "http-nio-0.0.0.0-8050-BlockPoller"
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "http-nio-0.0.0.0-8050-ClientPoller" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[2020-01-01 22:31:40.301][http-nio-8(54)][ERROR][o.a.t.u.n.NioBlockingSelector] Error processing selection key operations
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[2020-01-01 22:31:41.509][Camel (tar(36)][ERROR][o.a.c.p.DefaultErrorHandler] Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-DESKTOP-0AE8A58-1577885403576-0-2 on ExchangeId: ID-DESKTOP-0AE8A58-1577885403576-0-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-0AE8A58-1577885403576-0-1]

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[fileRoute         ] [fileRoute         ] [timer://timer1?period=2s&repeatCount=1                                        ] [     93317]
[fileRoute         ] [setBody1          ] [setBody[constant{SELECT * FROM TRANS_ONLINE_TRM_HST}]                         ] [        55]
[fileRoute         ] [to2               ] [jdbc:dataSource?outputType=StreamList&resetAutoCommit=false                   ] [     93246]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-0AE8A58-1577885403576-0-1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1842) ~[camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:385) ~[camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:64) ~[camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148) ~[camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:181) ~[camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) [camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:197) [camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:79) [camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556) [?:?]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[2020-01-01 22:31:41.530][Camel (tar(36)][WARN ][o.a.c.c.t.TimerConsumer] Error processing exchange. Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-0AE8A58-1577885403576-0-1]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException - Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-0AE8A58-1577885403576-0-1]]
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-0AE8A58-1577885403576-0-1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1842) ~[camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:385) ~[camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:64) ~[camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148) ~[camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:181) ~[camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) ~[camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) ~[camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) ~[camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:197) [camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:79) [camel-core-2.23.2.jar:2.23.2]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556) [?:?]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[2020-01-01 22:31:41.499][Catalina-u(51)][ERROR][o.a.c.c.StandardServer] Error sending periodic event
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startPeriodicLifecycleEvent(StandardServer.java:953) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer$1.run(StandardServer.java:941) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I think it's because SQL statements bring in the entire records at once.
How do I handle this issue?

Please let me know solution.

I think that the stat

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the client. An easy way to solve OutOfMemoryError in java is to increase the maximum heap size by using JVM options "-Xmx512M". Here is an example of increasing maximum heap size of JVM, Also its better to keep -Xmx to -Xms ration either 1:1 or 1:1.5 if you are setting heap size in your java application.

```
export JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
```

Another way to approach the problem is to reduce the fetch size when opening the cursor in jdbc:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
Statement st = conn.createStatement();

// Set fetch size for cursor.
st.setFetchSize(50);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable");
```

Comment: I want to know the real solution about this issue. We ca have max. about 8M records. Can I have solution with adjusting fetchSize?

Comment: This is not reflected in your question.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but your solution is not applied for camel context. Please let me know another solution by using camel jdbc component.